# Signing a kernel mode driver

Tags: windows, digital-certificate, kmdf

I have a kmfd driver and i am buying a certificate from http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/ , will this certificate work on windows 7 ? or do i need to buy it from verisign only , they charge a whopping 400$/yr whereas this is 178$/year .